# Why is this Java console animation so glitchy?

Tags: java, graphics, console

I made a program for the Java console and what I realised is that when I run it, the car is very glitchy as it passes from one end to the other..

What might be causing this?
Here's the code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import hsa.Console;
    import java.awt.Graphics;


    public class PracticingGraphics1
    {
      static Console c;           // The output console

      public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
        c = new Console ();
        c.setTextBackgroundColor(Color.blue);

    for (int x = 1 ; x > 0 ; x = x+1)
    {

      c.setColor(Color.RED);
      c.clear();
      c.fillRoundRect(x, 150, 150, 80, 10, 10);
      c.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      c.fillRect(0, 240, 800, 200);
      c.fillOval(x+130, 190, 50, 50);//left tire
      c.fillOval(x-20, 190, 50, 50);//right tire

      if(x >700){
        x = 1;
      }
      Thread.sleep (10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to either define "glichy" or provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably because you `clear()` before you draw the new car. You will have moments of emptiness. Since `clear()` removes everything, you would probably have to stop using it and draw the same car again with the same color as the background color to make it invisible **after** you have drawn the new car.

Comment: @azurefrog: I doubt that he can provide a mcve since few of us have the hsa library.

Comment: "I made a program for the Java console [...]" But you are using some self-written `hsa.Console`. Does not look like "the Java console" (whatever this is supposed to be, probably not `System.out`). Anyway, the way you use this "console" highly suggests to me that it is something closer a [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) than to a console.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a colored background, you don't need to clear (the call to clear will only make it glitch, as it will appear white for a short time). Simply drawing over the previous will have the affect of animation.